# Search snippet does not appear in Search API search page

Tags: 7, search

I am using

- Drupal 7.28
- Apache Solr 4.4.0
- Search API Solr 7.x-1.5
- Search API attachment 7.x-1.3 and
- Search API Page 7.x-1.1.

I have created 2 content types with
 - Title
 - ID
 - Document date (not the default node creation date)
 - Attachment

My index and preprocessing settings are the following: 
**Index Fields:** [image: index fields]
**Processor settings:**
[image: Processor settings]

In the search page I am searching all the fields and have set 
View mode: Themed as search results

The searches work correctly only that when I search for a keyword appearing in the attachment text, the results return without the search snippet, whereas when I search in the title, the returned result is correctly highlighted

The funny thing is that when I submit the query directly to solr with e.g. `q=tm_title:Spain?hl=on` the `<lst name="highlighting">` is empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that **Create Excerpt** was the option that was not allowing the search snippet to appear. After I disabled it, everything worked as expected. Should have done my homework better :-/

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for anyone stumbling upon this problem when using Display Suite: if you use the standard "search result highlighting input" view mode with the "search snippet" field, make sure to apply the patch in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1368984) to get results.

Also, under Advanced options in your solr server settings, make sure to enable "Return an excerpt for all results", "Retrieve result data from Solr" and "Highlight retrieved data".